# What kind of interaction phototelectric effect is?

Tags: photoelectric-effect, interactions, weak-interaction

All standard-elementary books which discuss modern physics quote the value of time of interaction for phototelectric effect to be less than $10^{-8}$ seconds. If the phenomenon takes about this time, which is large for an interaction, it has to be weak interaction. But isn't photoelectric interaction electromagnetic?

Comment: _If the phenomenon takes about this time, which is large for an interaction, it has to be weak interaction_.
Why do you say that?

Comment: Aren't interactions classified according to the time required by the process?

Comment: I came across this post: https://m.phys.org/news/2018-09-absolute-duration-photoelectric-effect.html. According to this, the time taken by photoelectric process is about $10^{-17}$ seconds which means the process is electromagnetic. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The interaction involves a photon so it must be electromagnetic. What process does that interaction time include?